# Show variable in erb Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to present different background images based on a css class that is named the same as the id of the item id but I can't get it to actually work... Here's what I have so far in my view:

```
<div class= "<% @city.id %>" style="background-color:white;">
```

And here's what it's rendering in the browser:

```
<div class style="background-color:white;">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot the "=", like so :

```
<%= @city.id %>
```